# インラインのコードブロックを含む長いコメントが折り返されない

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

画面中央右側、関連する質問とコメントが重なっている。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

当該コメント： https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/14555#comment13243_14618

---

Long comments break formatting as seen in the screenshot. Here is a link to a sample comment that breaks the layout:

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/14555#comment13243_14618

This is related to the following meta.SE post:

[Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow/42662#42662)

Comment: `.comment-text code`というCSSステートメントに`display: inline-block`を加えると、この問題を解決できるようです。しかし、古いブラウザーなどでは`display: inline-block`を使っていたら`code`タグは正常に表示されるかどうかはよく分かりません。

Comment: `inline-block`を使ったら、ワードブレイクにまで副作用もあるかもしれません。`table`という要素は内部のHTML要素のコンテンツによって自動に拡張していると思うので、`div`には固定幅を設定するのが解決になるかもしれません。例えば、`td.comment-text div.comment-body: {width: 630px;}`など。

Comment: @cypher コメントにはプラス投票をすることができますが、これが例えば100票ついたら、3桁の数字を表示する分コメント本文の幅が狭くなる必要があるので、本文の幅を固定することはできないようです。　http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42662/286934

Comment: @unarist ああ、そうですか。それなら、完全の解決にはなりませんけど、`max-width: 640px`とかを使ったら、問題を軽減できると思います。

Answer (score 5):

解決はしていませんが、調査した結果をまとめておきます。

まず、スペースなしの長文がコメントされた場合、80文字程度ごとに不可視の空白文字 `&zqnj;&#8023;` が埋め込まれることで正しく折り返されるようになっています。半角と全角で80文字の幅は異なりますが、全角文字はスペースがなくても折り返されるので基本的には問題ないです。

[Is there a CSS problem on Stack Overflow? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91512/286934)

で、問題のコメントを見ると多数のコードブロックが「を」「に、」だけでつながれていて、どうもこれがChromeの禁則処理に引っかかったようです。色々試していくと、

- コードブロックの間に禁則文字以外の全角二文字以上
- コードブロック内や前後に半角スペース
- コードブロックの末尾・禁則文字の直後以外に `&zwnj;&#8203;`
  （今回の80文字目はコードブロックの末尾で、ここではうまく折り返されないようです）

を足すとほぼ正しく折り返されたので、結構なレアケースですね。

回避策としては「半角スペースを入れる」というのが最も簡単だと思います。

コメントでも書きましたが、ボックス幅の固定は過去にJeff Atwood氏が否定しています。

> Near as I can tell, there is no way to get this to work on comments because they are variable width. That is, the actual comment size depends on whether or not the comment vote UI controls are present (fex, on your own comment, you don't have controls, if you're not logged in there are no controls, etc), and if the comment has say 100 upvotes that's wider still.
>   <sub>--- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42662/286934 より引用</sub>

確かに、あふれるぐらいなら多少ずれる方がマシってことでmax-width指定してもよさそうですが。

Google Chrome 44.0.2403.155 / Win8.1 / rev 2015.8.19.693

Comment: ChromeっつーかWebkitな。Safariでも起こっから。ただMobile Safariでは起こらん

Answer (score 3):

CSSのみでは折り返しの問題を解決できないので、以前から80文字ごとに見えない文字（"`&zwnj;&#8203;`"）を挿入していました。

この80文字という基準は西洋の言語ではちょうどいいのですが、日本語・中国語などの文字幅が広い言語、それから等幅ブロックでは、60文字前後で折り返す必要があるようです。

そこでどちらの言語でもうまく折り返すことができるように、見えない文字を20文字ずつに挿入するようにします。これで60文字・80文字どちらか適切な長さで折り返されるはずです。

次回のビルドに適用します。

---

There is no suitable CSS-only fix for this problem. What we did in the past was inserting an invisible optional line break ("`&zwnj;&#8203;`") every 80 characters.

Unfortunately, the default of 80 is optimal for western alphabets and writing, but does not work for languages whose fonts are larger (Japanese, Chinese) and for `monospace text`. The ideal size for those is breaking around 60 characters.

To accommodate both needs I've changed the code so we insert the invisible breaks every 20 characters. This should allow breaking at 60 and at 80, depending on what fits.

This will be out in the next deployment.