# コメント欄に長いURLを貼り付けた際、&hellip;という文字列が現れることがある

Tags: バグ, 完了, コメント

例えば、

http://web.archive.org/web/20030623161822/http://www.epkowa.co.jp/linux/DLinfo.html

というURLをコメント欄に書くと、次のように表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

長いURLを省略した際の `…` を表すHTMLエンティティがそのまま出ているようです。

---

When you add a long URL in a comment, `&hellip;` gets inserted. This may be associated with [this fixed bug](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2268/10).

Comment: 例 http://web.archive.org/web/20030623161822/http://www.epkowa.co.jp/linux/DLinfo.html

Comment: @jmac 直ったんでしょうか・・・？

Comment: 確認中です。再現ができていないが、なぜかがわかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

開発者が治しました。コーナーケース以外（何十文字の最後のある文字があるとか）に大丈夫です。